# Django: Selecting model and ordering by sub-models create details

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    closed = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    closed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

class Letter(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    letter_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    deleted = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    deleted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

    def lastVersion(self):
    return self.letterversion_set.order_by('created').latest().created

class LetterVersion(models.Model):
    letter = models.ForeignKey(Letter)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.TextField()

    def letterItem(self):
    return self.letter.item
```

When a `Letter` is edited a new `Letter Version` is created. I am trying to select the last 3 `Letter`s that have been edited recently using `LetterVersion.create`. I have the following in my `views.py`:

```
lettersAll = Letter.objects.filter(item=i_iID,deleted__isnull=True).order_by('-letterversion__created')[:3]
```

Unfortunately this will get me the last 3 `LetterVersion`s basted on their created date/time even if they are from the same `Letter`.

```
letter 1 version 3 [1]
letter 3 version 4 [2]
letter 1 version 2 [3]
letter 1 version 1
letter 2 version 2
letter 2 version 1
letter 3 version 3
letter 3 version 2
letter 3 version 1
```

Where I want:

```
letter 1 version 3 [1]
letter 3 version 4 [2]
letter 2 version 2 [3]
```

Is there anyway I can get a list of the last 3 letters edited?

Comment: just to point out to other people that maybe looking at this post and wondering if there is a name for what I describing , it's called `Aggregation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `annotate()` them with the `Max()` of `letterversion__created`, and then `order_by()` that.

```
from django.db.models import Max

lettersAll = Letter.objects.filter(
        item=i_iID,
        deleted__isnull=True
    ).annotate(
        last_created_version=Max('letterversion_created')
    ).order_by('-last_created_version')[:3]
```

Comment: Yep, was in the process of adding one.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. Doesn't the `Max('letterversion_created')` find the version with the newest/largest date and hence `order_by('-last_created_version')` becomes `order_by('last_created_version')`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: No - it finds the newest date *for each item*. The `-` still applies to sorting between the items. Also, `-` is not "inverse" - it's always "descending". Descending max is still descending.

Comment: How does it know that `Max('letterversion_created')` is for `LetterVersions` relating to the `Letter` and not just all letters?

Comment: @Sevenearths because it's modifying an existing `Letter.objects` querymanager object, and thus uses the related `LetterVersion` field on that object.